# Why i'm not getting null exception if the variable is null?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using unfreez_wrapper;
using Shell32;


namespace DownloadImages
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string rainMapToRead;
        string UrlsPath;
        int counter;
        UnFreezWrapper uf;
        string localFilename;
        string stringForSatelliteMapUrls;
        string satelliteMapToRead;
        List<string> StartTags;
        List<string> LastTags;
        List<string> Maps;

        ExtractImages ei;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();




                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=1&continent=europa#",localFilename + "rainMap.html");
                    client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/en/eu?ir=true", localFilename + "satelliteMap.html");
                }

                rainMapToRead = File.ReadAllText(localFilename + "rainMap.html");
                satelliteMapToRead = File.ReadAllText(localFilename + "satelliteMap.html");
```

localFileName was before a path to a directory.
But now i didn't define it so it's null.
But even when it's null the rainMapToRead is not null and was able to find and read the "rainMap.html"

I mean if the variable localFilename is null where the file was downloded to ? C: ? D: ?
In case it's null what is the default location ?

Comment: Using null in string concatenation results in an empty string.`Console.WriteLine(null + "foo");` prints `foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bacause this `(null + " hello")` is perfectly legitimate expression in `C#`.

If you look on [How to: Concatenate Multiple Strings (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms228504.aspx), you can find following statement:

> In string concatenation operations, the C# compiler treats a null
>   string the same as an empty string, but it does not convert the value
>   of the original null string.

Answer (score 3):

Concatenating null valid, you won't get any exception. This is what is happening

```
null + "satelliteMap.html" = "satelliteMap.html"
```

Provided that's a relative location, the file will be stored on the phisycal location of the exe.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228362.aspx)

> By contrast, a null string does not refer to an instance of a System.String object and any attempt to call a method on a null string causes a NullReferenceException. However, you can use null strings in concatenation and comparison operations with other strings.

Answer (score 0):

The concat (`+`) operator just treats `null` as an empty string.

The path used is the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

The default location is the same location as the executable.

So, if your executable is running at `C:\MyProgram\`, the `WebClient` will download the file to `C:\MyProgram\rainMap.html`.. and your `rainMapToRead` will read from `C:\MyProgram\rainMap.html`.

This is because `null + "String"` == `"String"`